# Working with Sentinel-2 data and aggrigation in R

Tags: large-datasets, aggregation

So I was wandering if there is a way to simplify a couple of Sentinel's rasters so I can apply raster analysis on them. Problem is that whenever I try to aggregate the data my RAM, CPU and storage overload (see the following line). And that is by using parallel processing.

```
r2=aggregate(ras,fact=10,fun=mean, expand=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Now I am wandering, if there is a faster way to transform my data, faster, using another method or function. Now, I have also thought of resample and splitting but I wanted to ask you people if you knew a faster way to aggregate my data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `velox`:

```
library(raster)
library(velox)
library(microbenchmark)
library(RStoolbox) # FOR DATA

data('lsat')

test_data <- lsat[[1]]

microbenchmark(a = raster::aggregate(x = test_data, fact = 10, fun = mean, expand = T, na.rm = T),
               b = {v <- velox(test_data); v$aggregate(factor = c(10,10), aggtype = 'mean')})

## Unit: milliseconds
## expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval cld
## a 36.975760 40.361677 46.470796 42.326149 46.097733 327.624192   100   b
## b  1.070906  1.462487  1.982737  1.772933  2.037216   7.178011   100  a
```

Comment: ok, I missed something here. Velox works, but I can't even plot my aggregated raster. For example: here is my line (based on your example)

`v <- velox("path/to/raster.tif")`
`v$aggregate(factor = c(10,10), aggtype = 'mean')` 

Am I doing something wrong? How do I call the aggregated result?

Comment: A velox object is not suitable with raster methods. Convert it to raster `r <- v$as.RasterLayer()` and you can plot and do anything as a normal raster. Also, there are `$as.RasterStack()` and `$as.RasterBrick()`